# explode или preg_split с несколькоими разделителями

Tags: php

Привет.

Есть строка, содержащая два числа. Как разбить строку на массив, если числа могут разделяться или пробелом или запятой? А ещё пользователь может ввести несколько пробелов и строку всё-равно нужно разделить на два числа.

По идее следует использовать preg_split. Помогите с регулярочкой *_*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна такая строка вызова

```
$returnValue = preg_split('/[ ,]+/', '123  , 343', -1);
```

распарсит и `123 2323`, `123, 434`. Но также распарсит и `123 , , , 232`.

**UPD**

Но если пользователи совсем ленивые и хочется, что бы они вводили как курка лапой (иногда и так нужно), тогда лучше использовать чуточку другую функцию.

```
# строка от супервежливого пользователя
$user_input =  'here is my numbers: 234  and   435';
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/(\\d+).+?(\\d+)/',$user_input, $matches);
$v1 = $matches[1];
$v2 = $matches[2];

print_r($matches);
```